# Javascript try-catch doesn't catch 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET '

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, try-catch

I have a multiple file uploader but while it's uploading sometimes 1 out of 10 files doesn't make it and it returns a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in chrome console. I tried to catch it with the try-catch, but it acts as if no error occurred. What am I doing wrong?

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "/multiFileUploadHandler.php");
try {
    ajax.send(formdata);
} catch (err) {
    alert('Error: '+err);
}
```

Comment: usually this error happens when the server's transport detected a error condition and thus it does reset your TCP/IP connection ! :)

Answer (score 6):

This is likely because it is async. Try catching this with an onerror event handler.

```
ajax.onerror = function(error) {
    // handle error
};
```

edit: corrected syntax.